# Analyze Table Optimization in Databricks for Views

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

After doing Analyze Table Compute Statistics performance of my joins got better in Databricks Delta table.
As in Spark sql Analyze view is not supported. I would like to know if the query Optimizer will optimize the query if I have a view created on the same table on which I have used Analyze table compute statistics.

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Analyze View that I know of.

> From the manuals: Define a logical view on one or more tables or
>   views.

It is logical. But the View will be expanded, merged, compiled, materialized and the sum total of the SQL statements will be subject to optimization. E.g. a JOIN of a View with another View or Table will lead to optimization of the base level components - the Tables along with the operations e.g. a JOIN, sub-select.

So, the Table stats are important, but also the intended set of operations for the Optimizer.

So, the answer to your question is Yes.